# Why does JavaScript returns undefined on a created object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object that returns a bunch of questions. It seems working, but at the last line it prints out undefined four times without any space or line break. I don't know what I did that caused that.

Here is my Code:

```js
// Creating an object constructor function
function Person_practice(questiona, questionb, questionc, questiond, questione) {
  this.questiona = questiona;
  this.questionb = questionb;
  this.questionc = questionc;
  this.questiond = questiond;
  this.questione = questione;
  this.alertAllQuestion = function() {
    return this.questiona + this.questionb + this.questionc + this.questiond + this.questione;
  }
}

// Making a variable for storing all questions so it is sent back to the constructor
var b = new Person_practice("What is 1 + 1<br>", "What is 2 + 2<br>", "What is 3 + 3<br>", "What is 4 + 4<br>", "What is 5 + 5<br>");

// Use the document.getElementById() method to select the p element and print out the question
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = b.alertAllQuestion();
```

```html
<p id="myDiv"></p>
```

Also when I use `document.getElementById()` method inside the alertAllQuestion method, it only returns undefined. If I change it to this, it returns out my questions and the undefined.

Comment: `Person_practice` constructor expects 5 arguments, but you're passing only a single argument.

Comment: So if I change it to var b = new Person_practice("What is 1+1", "What is 2+2", "What is 3+3", "What is 4+4", "What is 5+5"); then it will work right?

Comment: Just try it ...

Comment: It works, but I want to insert line breaks between then so it is more readable. If I did this correctly, I think the code should look like this: var b = new Person_practice("What is 1+1 +'<br>'", + "What is 2+2 + '<br>'" so on

Comment: You don't need to separate the b tags, just include them in the string: `What is 1+1<br>`.

Comment: Can you explain why when I changed return to document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML on my code, returns undefined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228229/discussion-between-toby-harnish-and-teemu).

Comment: The method doesn't return `undefined`, you can see the result also in the question, I made a live Stack Snippet of your code.

Comment: Go to https://www.theharnishes.com/object.html and you'll see the undefined message.

Comment: You're doing something wrong, compare your real code carefully to what you have here, maybe you'll find a difference.

Comment: I think I changed return to document.getElementById(). However, I want to know why it returned undefined when I used document.getElementById() method inside alertAllQuestion() method.